# How to define real number in agda?

Tags: agda, dependent-type

I want to implement Dedekind's cut in Agda. I tried to represent real number first. But I am not able to define it in Agda. How to define it??

Comment: The HoTT book ([link](http://homotopytypetheory.org/book/)) has a section precisely about Dedekind reals. I'm not sure how helpful it is, but you can check it out regardless.

Comment: You might be able to get some inspiration from [Formalization of Real Analysis: A Survey of
Proof Assistants and Libraries](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-00806920v1/document).

Answer (score 3):

Real numbers can be constructed in a [few different ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers):

Following Erret Bishop's construction of real numbers in *Constructive Analysis*, real numbers can be formalized in Agda as a sequence of rational numbers along with a proof of convergence of this sequence:

```
-- Constructible Real numbers as described by Bishop
-- A real number is defined to be a sequence along 
-- with a proof that the sequence is regular
record ℝ : Set where
  constructor Real
  field
    f : ℕ -> ℚ
    reg : {n m : ℕ} -> ∣ f n - f m ∣ ≤ (suc n)⁻¹ + (suc m)⁻¹
```

Checkout [this repository](https://github.com/MrChico/agda-stdlib/blob/clean/src/Data/Real.agda) for the formalized construction of an equivalence relation using this definition.

Another way to define real numbers is with Dedekind cuts, which as @vitrus mentioned, is discussed in chapter 11 in [the Homotopy Type Theory book](http://homotopytypetheory.org/book/)

Comment: Just to highlight, for bystanders: The Agda-implementation of the Bishopy-style definition of the Cauchy real numbers shown above has recently been developed a little further by Zachary Murray: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cauchy+real+number#Murray22 https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.08354